# Defeating the Array<T> and IObservableArray<T> incompatibility

Tags: typescript, types, mobx, mobx-react

Assume I have some property in my store that is being array of some type `MyType` and *decorated* with observable:

```
class MyStore {
    @observable array
}
```

I know that in normal world this should be an `Array<MyType>`. But when I'm declaring it in this way,

```
class MyStore {
    @observable array: Array<MyType>
}
```

then I lose the method `.remove(item: MyType)`. On the other hand, if I'm declaring it with `IObservableArray<MyType>`,

```
class MyStore {
    @observable array: IObservableArray<MyType>
}
```

then I lose a possibility to legally assign an `Array<MyType>` values to this prop (under *legally* I mean assigning without construction `... as IObservableArray<MyType>` - disadvantages of this method are too obvious: a lot of unnecessary code, the type should be imported whenever it used, etc.)

I also tried to use union and intersection types:

1. Intersection (`Array<MyType> & IObservableArray<MyType>`) produces an error during assigning an `Array<MyType>` value to this prop: `Property 'spliceWithArray' is missing in type MyType`.
2. Union (`Array<MyType> | IObservableArray<MyType>`) still causes lost of method `.remove(item: MyType)`.

Am I missing or misunderstanding something? Is there any legal way to defeat it? Thank you all in advance!

---

By the way, the `mobx` version I'm using is `4`, because it is necessary for me to support old iPads, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the next syntax, this won't generate any TS errors. And you can safely use methods of both `Array` and `IObservableArray`

```js
class MyStore {
  readonly array = observable<MyType>([])

  @action
  getItems() {
    api.getItems<MyType[]>().then((response) => this.array.replace(response.data));
  }

  @action
  removeItem(item: MyType) {
    this.array.remove(item);
  }
}
```

**readonly** - as you are mostly not intended to do an assignment for `array` property, like `this.array = itemsFromServer`

**replace, remove** - methods of IObservableArray

Comment: Great! Thank you :)
Didn't notice this `replace` method, it is so useful in this case

Answer (score 1):

How about creating your own tailored type, extending Array class and manually implementing the IObservableArray methods as optional?

Since you are locked to mobx@4.6.0, there's no problem with the maintaining the interface as the version advances.

it's not ideal but it's the only way I can think of that will allow you to assign Array and also use methods like .remove().

I call the type **MyExtendedObservableArray**:

```
import {IArrayChange, IArraySplice, IArrayWillChange, IArrayWillSplice, IInterceptor, IObservableArray, Lambda, observable} from "mobx";

interface MyExtendedObservableArray<T> extends Array<T>{
    spliceWithArray?(index: number, deleteCount?: number, newItems?: T[]): T[];
    observe?(listener: (changeData: IArrayChange<T> | IArraySplice<T>) => void, fireImmediately?: boolean): Lambda;
    intercept?(handler: IInterceptor<IArrayWillChange<T> | IArrayWillSplice<T>>): Lambda;
    clear?(): T[];
    peek?(): T[];
    replace?(newItems: T[]): T[];
    find?(predicate: (item: T, index: number, array: IObservableArray<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any, fromIndex?: number): T | undefined;
    findIndex?(predicate: (item: T, index: number, array: IObservableArray<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any, fromIndex?: number): number;
    remove?(value: T): boolean;
    move?(fromIndex: number, toIndex: number): void;
    toJS?(): T[];
    toJSON?(): T[];
}

class MyType{}
let myType = new MyType();

class MyStore {
    @observable array: MyExtendedObservableArray<MyType> = [myType] 
    // no TSC compilation error
}
```

Comment: Not bad solution, but this interface should be also imported, and in this case it is much easier to import `IObservableArray` from `mobx` and then just assign as `this.someObservableArray = someArray as IObservableArray`. Unfortunately, the solution you have provided does not solve the main problem with conveniens of usage(

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance
 I'm not sure I understand. In my solution you don't need to import anything. The MyExtendedObservableArray has all the methods of both IObservableArray and Array. 
So it's enough to assign a regular array and you will have the mobx methods on it without importing or using "as ...." notation.

The only place where you need to import it is once in the class definition (which i think is something you cannot avoid anyway)

Comment: oh, sry, I misunderstood you. Well, then, seems like this is the only way to defeat the problem. This is not as convenient as I wish, but seems like it works) Thank you for the answer!